# How to overwrite all fields when inserting a duplicate record into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Suppose you have a table with a single record, where the first field (with value "ID100") is the primary key.

```
('ID100', 'b', 'c', 'd', 256)
```

Now suppose you want to insert the tuple

```
('ID100', 'e', 'f', 'g', 123)
```

Which has a duplicate primary key.

The end result should be a table with a single record:

```
('ID100', 'e', 'f', 'g', 123)
```

How do you write an insert statement to overwrite all of the fields in cases like this where the primary key conflicts?

I have looked at this guide: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/ ... but I don't see how to overwrite all of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use `on conflict`

```
insert into the_table (id, col2, col3, col4, col5)
values ('ID100', 'b', 'c', 'd', 256)
on conflict (id) do update
   set col2 = excluded.col2,
       col3 = excluded.col3, 
       col4 = excluded.col4, 
       col5 = excluded.col5;
```

Comment: I have 143 fields, so doing it this way would be a major pain... My question is how to do this automatically without enumerating all of the fields. Is this possible?

Comment: In that case, I suggest you delete the record if it exists - and do the insert - without the use of conflict.